# how to maintain the speed of scroller?

Tags: android

I have a problem while using the scroller in my application.

I have used the scroller but it is not working properly as it is not able to maintain a consistent speed while automatically scrolling. The speed of the text is getting slower with time as the text moves upward.

Here is the code that I used for this purpose:

```
length = prompt_text.getLineCount();
Log.d("length",""+length);
prompt_text.setScroller(scroll);
scroll.startScroll(0,0,0,10 * length, 100000 / speedAmount);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting up the Scroller interpolator as a LinearInterpolator?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html#Scroller(android.content.Context,%20android.view.animation.Interpolator)

Sample:

```
yourScroller = new Scroller(yourContext, new LinearInterpolator());
```

Comment: THANKS, can you please give example as i don't know about interpolator