# how to maintain the speed of scroller?

Tags: android, scroll

I am new to android programming. In my application, i want to implement automatic scrolling. So, i used scroller for this purpose.It is performing scrolling but not maintaining constant speed till the end of scrolling the text. Can anyone help me out of this problem. 
Here, is the code used for scrolling:

```
prompt_text.setScroller(scroll);
scroll.startScroll(scroll_x,scroll_y,0,50 * speedAmount, 100000/speedAmount);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to maintain the speed of scroller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242544/how-to-maintain-the-speed-of-scroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking an already answered question by the same person will not lead to anything further the same answer
[how to maintain the speed of scroller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242544/how-to-maintain-the-speed-of-scroller/4243273#4243273)

Answer (score 2):

You can use scroller with interpolation in it as parameter